# Create Mono Array Object with keeping original ordering

Tags: java, kotlin, reactor

I need to implement function that returns Mono< Array< ProcessedObject>>. As argument it takes list of objects and process them with function that returns Mono< ProcessedObject>. Function needs to keep original order, meaning first element on returned list must be created from first element from argument list. So far i have following solution but it doesn't keep required order. Is it even possible with Flux?

```
       private fun createItems(objects: List<Someobjects>): Mono<Array<ProcessedObject>> {
         return Flux.fromIterable(objects)
           .flatMap {
             processObject(it)
           }.collectList().map { it.toTypedArray() }
}
```

Edit: to clarify a little processObject returns Mono< ProcessedObject>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`.

Here is a link for the Docu https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-

```
private fun createItems(objects: List<Someobjects>): Mono<Array<ProcessedObject> {
         return Flux.fromIterable(objects)
           .concatMap {
             processObject(it)
           }.collectList().map { it.toTypedArray() }
}
```

The difference between flatMap and concatMap is that the later preserves the original order.